# Filter true meaning in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop

If at least one of the values returned from the loop is true, the function must return true.
How can I do this?

```
  const addCart = () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < props.cart.length; i++) {
      return props.cart[i].domainName === props.domainName;
    }
  };
```

Comment: Please see [Does return stop a loop?](/q/11714503/4642212).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
const addCart = () => {
  // here we use Array.prototype.some(),
  // which returns a Boolean; true if any
  // of the array-elements match the provided
  // assessment, or false if not:
  return props.cart.some(
    (cart) => cart.domainName === props.domainName
  );
}
```

References:

- [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
- [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code.

```js
const addCart = () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < props.cart.length; i++) {
    if (props.cart[i].domainName === props.domainName) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
};
```

The function returns true when the first equal property has been found.  It gives you the possibility to obtain the result without checking all elements of the array.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) here

```
const addCart = () => {
  if (props.cart.some((o) => o.domainName === props.domainName)) return true;
  return false;
};
```

or simply using single liner solution

```
const addCart = () => props.cart.some((o) => o.domainName === props.domainName);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const addCart = () => props.cart.some(e=>e.domainName===props.domainName);
```